# Spring Expression Language (SpEL), Can we loop over the list?

Tags: spring, loops, spring-el

Can we loop over the array list using SpEL?

Background,

I am using SpEL to dynamically generate some templates, thus I need to loop over some lists. I did not find any way to loop over the list using SpEL.

e.g something like #foreach in velocity

Comment: You can use jstl tags to iterate it

Comment: I am doing all in back end. JSP is not involved.